# database restore for integration tests with phpunit

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, integration-testing

I'm using phpunit and I'd like to know if there is a correct form for restoring the database before running integration tests. At the moment I'm calling an sql server script with php exec() on the testcase setUp method, but don't know if this is the best choice

```
class TestCase extends PHPUnit_FrameWork_TestCase {
    protected function setUp() {
        exec("the restore command line");
    }
}
```

Is there a more correct form to do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [DbUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html) is all about. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since I am not using PDO, how can I handle the setUp and tearDown? Do I have to implement PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection?

Comment: The code under test does not have to use PDO. But DbUnit relies on PDO.

Comment: I'm new on phpunit, helped me a lot, thank you very much!